# Adding existing project in c#

Tags: c#

I have add the existing project in my new project, but when I try to use the existing library, I see the following error:

> the type or namespace name 'com' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What would cause this?

Comment: Is there really a `com` namespace, or did you just mistype something?

Answer (score 0):

you must add in your main project reference to other project

(project's property -> add reference -> projects -> select your second project )

or you must add

```
    using com;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added the reference to the project then try adding a `using` for the added class in the .cs file where you want to use it:

```
using com;
```

Comment: I doubt that's what the problem is.  More likely, the OP typed `com` somewhere they shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the name of the project you want to add the library **to** > Select **Add Reference**, in the dialog box, > select Projects. > Select and ADD the library.

Reference the library in the ‘using’ section of any class you wish to access the library.

```
using System;
using <nameofproject>
```

Also read this article.

> http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/02/namespaces-in-c/

Comment: In C#, `using` has to be lowercase.

Comment: @svick Word strikes again. Nice catch. Though if typing it (not pasting) the code editor will automatically correct it.